# Asterisk transmit_silence and WaitForSilence/WaitForNoise

Tags: asterisk

I have an Asterisk application that needs to record the audio with the MixMonitor command, and also use the WaitForNoise/WaitForSilence commands.

The problem arises when calls are coming in via a provider that uses silence suppression, then the audio recording is chopped (because the silence is not recorded).

I used 'transmit_silence=yes' in asterisk.conf, and that fixes the recording, but then the WaitForNoise/WaitForSilence commands are not working correctly.

Is there any way to fix that by either canceling somehow the silence suppression on incoming calls, or having another Asterisk system in between (to revert the effect of silence suppression)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel silence suppression of PROVIDER side.

You can play with silence treshold in dsp.conf.